# How to integrate with Google Plus

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, social-networking, google-plus

How to configure google application inside https://code.google.com/apis/console/ to integrate with Google Plus. I need common for all the networks functionallity like getting friends, writing on the wall etc.

Fortunately google provides C# sample but it doesn't works, probably because of incorrect configuration.

I am using C# .NET.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with google-app-engine ? I can't see any relationship based on the question.

Comment: I want to integrate with Google Plus like with any other social networks, facebook or twitter... And I'd like to know, how to configure app inside google apis console

Answer (score 3):

The Google+ API is somewhat different than the API for other social networks. In particular, you cannot write directly to a user's wall without them taking an explicit "share" like action.

For details about using the Google+ API, including some step-by-step examples of how to configure your project in the Developer's Console, see http://developers.google.com/+/

Answer (score 1):

Prisoner makes some great points about the API overall!

Also, it looks like you're trying to get started using Google+ in C#. There are a couple samples out there, but the latest one that Google has shipped is on GitHub:

http://github.com/googleplus

There are instructions for getting started with the sample here:

http://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp

If you have specific questions related to Google+ in C#, please refine your answer or ask in comments on this response.

Comment: I'd like to do some specific thing. I'd like to authenticate on mobile device and then provide something like auth token to the server, so that server will be able to make requests to GPlus api

Comment: What is the device OS / server type?

Comment: Device - Android, ( iOS ver. is coming soon too ), Server - ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API, C#